# Sum and alternating sum of a series of Bernoullian variates

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Consider the random variables
$a_i,i=0,1,\ldots,n$ be random variables which take values from $\{-1,1\}$ independently and randomly with equal probability. Let
\begin{align}
S &= a_1+\cdots+a_n  , \\
A &= a_1-a_2+a_3+\cdots .
\end{align}
I want to  compute the probability that $S. A<0$.

Here is my attempt:

**Attempt**
Let $E_1$ be the event that $S>0$ and $E_2$ be the event that $A>0.$ To simplify things assume $n$ is even, to begin with.

We observe that $S>0$ if more than half of $a_i$'s are +1. Next, for the alternating sum $A$, we have $A<0$ when $S>0$, if more of the $a_i$'s that contribute to $S$ have an odd index than an even index. Precisely, we want $ 2P(E_1 \cap E_2)$. We have:

\begin{equation}
P(E_1 \cap E_2)=P(E_1 | E_2)P(E_2)=P(E_2 | E_1)P(E_1)
\end{equation}

Now,
\begin{align}
P(E_1) &= P(S>0) \\
& =\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \binom{n}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{2^n}.
\end{align}

So,

\begin{equation}
P(E_2 | E_1) = P(A<0 | S>0).
\end{equation}

If $k \geq \frac{n}{2}+1$ are $+1$'s, then for $A$ to be negative, at least
$\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor+1$ have to have odd indices. That means,

$$
P(E_1 \cap E_2)=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \sum_{\ell=\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor+1}^k \binom{k}{\ell}}{2^k}
$$

Therefore, we have:
\begin{equation}
P(E_1 \cap E_2) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \sum_{\ell=\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor+1}^k \binom{k}{\ell}  \frac{1}{2^k} \cdot \displaystyle\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \binom{n}{k}  \frac{1}{2^n}.
\end{equation}

Since we have $S A$, even when $S<0$ and $A>0$, by symmetry, we conclude that the probability $S A<0$ is twice the probability given above. Hence the probability

\begin{equation}
P(E_1 \cap E_2) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \sum_{\ell=\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor+1}^k \binom{k}{\ell}  \frac{1}{2^k} \cdot \displaystyle \left(\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \binom{n}{k}  \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \right).
\end{equation}

However, I am not sure whether this approach or my solution is correct. Kindly  correct me and point out the mistakes, if any.

Comment: (i) Asking people to check your calculations is not encouraged on MathOverflow. (ii) Your derivation is mostly incomprehensible to me. (iii) Your conclusion is almost certainly incorrect, as you can check for some small values of $n$. (iv) Do you have a response to my answer on this page?

Answer (score 2):

We have $S=U+V$ and $A=U-V$, where
\begin{equation}
    U:=a_1+a_3+\cdots+a_{2k-1},\quad V:=a_2+a_4+\cdots+a_{2l},
\end{equation}
$k:=\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor$, $l:=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$. Then $k+l=n$; $U$ and $V$ are independent random variables (r.v.'s); the r.v. $B:=(U+k)/2$ has the binomial distribution with parameters $k,1/2$; the r.v. $C:=(V+l)/2$ has the binomial distribution with parameters $l,1/2$. So,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    p_n:=&P(SA<0) \\ 
    &=P((U+V)(U-V)<0) \\ 
    &=P(U^2<V^2) \\ 
    &=P(|U|<|V|) \\ 
    &=\sum_{v=-l}^l P(V=v)\sum_{u=1-|v|}^{|v|-1}P(U=u) \\ 
    &=2\sum_{v=1}^l P(V=v)\sum_{u=1-v}^{v-1}P(U=u) \\ 
    &=2\sum_{v=1}^l P(C=(v+l)/2)\sum_{u=1-v}^{v-1}P(B=(u+k)/2) \\ 
    &=2\sum_{v=1}^l 2^{-l}\binom l{(v+l)/2}1(v\equiv l)
    \sum_{u=1-v}^{v-1}2^{-k}\binom k{(u+k)/2}1(u\equiv k) \\ 
    &=2^{1-n}\sum_{v=1}^l \binom l{(v+l)/2}1(v\equiv l)
    \sum_{u=1-v}^{v-1}\binom k{(u+k)/2}1(u\equiv k), 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $a\equiv b$ means that $a-b$ is even.

The latter expression for $p_n$ has now been [greatly simplified](https://mathoverflow.net/a/450598/36721), and that result has been checked for $n=1,\dots,10$.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that my attempted solution in the question is incorrect.,here is  a my  new attempt to answer the question using the approach suggested in the original (incorrect ) solution.It would have been too long for a comment .However the answer is not some elegant expression.\begin{align}
S &= a_1+\cdots+a_n  , \\
A &= a_1-a_2+a_3+\cdots .
\end{align}
I want to  compute the probability that $S. A<0$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $E_1$ be the event that $S>0$ and $E_2$ be the event that $A>0.$ To simplify things assume $n$ is even, to begin with.

We observe that $S>0$ if more than half of $a_i$'s are +1. . We have:

\begin{equation}
P(E_1 \cap E_2)=P(E_1 | E_2)P(E_2)=P(E_2 | E_1)P(E_1)
\end{equation}

Now,
\begin{align}
P(E_1) &= P(S>0) \\
& =\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \binom{n}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{2^n}.
\end{align}.
Now to compute  $P(E_2 | E_1)$ we make the following simple  observation:

**Every +1 at an even place will contribute  negatively    and every -1 will contribute to positively in the alternating sum $A$** 
So given $S>0,$ we would wish to enumerate the ways in which the alternating sum $A$ can be negative .Let the number of +1's and the number of -1's that go to even places be respectively $l$ and $m.$ Since the  total number of even places is  $ \frac n2 ,$ we have the following constraints :
$$ 0 \leq l \leq \min\{ n/2,k\}$$ and
$$ 0 \leq m \leq  \min\{ n/2-l,n-k\}$$
With this arrangement and assuming $E_1$ ,the value the alternating sum will become:$$ (k-l)-l-(n-k-m)+m=2k-2l+2m-n$$ and this we need to be less than zero.
so the number of ways of arranging $k>n/2$ +1's and $n-k$ -1's  so that $A<0$ can be expressed as $$ \displaystyle \sum_{k=n/2+1}^{n-1} \binom{k}{l} \binom{n-k}{m} \binom{n-l-m}{k-l}  $$ subject to the constraints :
\begin{align}
 & 0 \leq l \leq \min\{ n/2,k\} \\  
& 0 \leq m \leq  \min\{ n/2-l,n-k\}\\
 &2k-2l+2m-n<0
\end{align}
This will give us  us $P(E_2|E_1),$ after we take the probability of this arrangement into account.However ,I am stuck at this  which is to be multiplied by \begin{align}
P(E_1) &= P(S>0) \\
& =\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \binom{n}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{2^n}
\end{align}.to get the requisite probability.Again ,it is my humble request  to that mistakes ,if any be pointed out and kindly tell me whether solution using this approach is even possible.